# Destructure a deeply nested object with one of its parents being an array in Javascript in one line

Tags: javascript, web, node.js

I have an object I'd like to destructure in one line a nested object that has an array as a parent. Given the below object, can this even be destructured in one line?

```
const deepObj = {
  allInformation: {
    edges: [
      {
        node: {
          address: 'Never Never Land',
          email: 'daffyduck@neverneverland',
          phoneNumber: '146 246'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

// one liner object destructuring in function signature?? 
const oneLiner = (deepObj) => (...)
```

The goal is to access the `address`, `email` and `phoneNumber` variables within the function signature.

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand what you're after. This seems like it does what you want: `const oneLiner = ({ address, email, phoneNumber }) => {...}; for (let curObj of deepObj.allInformation.edges) { oneLiner(curObj.node) };`.

Comment: Possible to do, but *very* unreadable, I'd highly recommend against it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the object always has value at every level, you could do something like this:

```js
const deepObj = {
  allInformation: {
    edges: [
      {
        node: {
          address: 'Never Never Land',
          email: 'daffyduck@neverneverland',
          phoneNumber: '146 246'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

// one liner object destructuring in function signature?? 
const oneLiner = ({ allInformation: { edges: [{ node: { address, email, phoneNumber} } ] } }) => {
  console.log(address)
  console.log(email)
  console.log(phoneNumber)
}

oneLiner(deepObj)
```

If any of those nested objects could be undefined, you'd have to add an empty object as default value like this:

```
node: { address, email, phoneNumber} = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this,

```js
const deepObj = {allInformation: {edges: [{node: {address: 'Never Never Land',email: 'daffyduck@neverneverland',phoneNumber: '146 246'}}]}}

// one liner object destructuring in function signature?? 
const oneLiner = ({
  allInformation: {
    edges: [{
      node: {
        email,
        address,
        phoneNumber
      }
    }]
  }
}) => {
  console.log(address)
  console.log(email)
  console.log(phoneNumber)
}

oneLiner(deepObj)
```

But if i had to do it i will use de-structure them in such a way to keep it readable and easy to debug

```js
const deepObj = {allInformation: {edges: [{node: {address: 'Never Never Land',email: 'daffyduck@neverneverland',phoneNumber: '146 246'}}]}}

const oneLiner = (obj) => {
  let {allInformation} = obj 
  let {edges} = allInformation || {}
  let {node} = edges[0] || {}
  let {address,email,phoneNumber} = node || {}
  
  console.log(address)
  console.log(email)
  console.log(phoneNumber)
}

oneLiner(deepObj)
```